# Efficiently integrate a series into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with index `[0, 1, 2...]`, and a list something like this: `[1, 2, 2, 0, 1...]`.

I'd like to add a 'count' column to the dataframe, that reflects the number of times the digit in the index is referenced in the list.

Given the example lists above, the 'count' column would have the value `2` at index `2`, because 2 occurred twice (so far).  Is there a more efficient way to do this than iterating over the list?

Comment: Yes, do you need a pandas df to do this though?

Comment: @EdChum - I am using the dataframe for other things too, the first step is getting the counts of occurrences into the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is a way of doing it, first load the list into a df, then add the 'occurrence' column using `value_counts` and then `merge` this to your orig df:

```
In [61]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(10)})
l=[1,2,2,0,1]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['data'])
df1['occurence'] = df1['data'].map(df1['data'].value_counts())
df1

Out[61]:
   data  occurence
0     1          2
1     2          2
2     2          2
3     0          1
4     1          2

In [65]:
df.merge(s, left_index=True, right_on='data',how='left').fillna(0).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

Out[65]:
   a  data  count
0  0     0      1
1  1     1      2
2  2     2      2
3  3     3      0
4  4     4      0
5  5     5      0
6  6     6      0
7  7     7      0
8  8     8      0
9  9     9      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting occurences of numbers in a dataframe is easy in pandas

You just use the [Series.value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) method.

Then you join the grouped dataframe with the original one using the [pandas.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) function.

Setting up a DataFrame like the one you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nomnom':np.random.choice(['cookies', 'biscuits', 'cake', 'lie'], 10)})
```

df is now a DataFrame with some arbitrary data in it (since you said you had more data in there).

```
     nomnom
0  biscuits
1       lie
2  biscuits
3      cake
4       lie
5   cookies
6      cake
7      cake
8      cake
9      cake
```

Setting up a list like the one you have:

```
yourlist = np.random.choice(10, 10)
```

yourlist is now:

```
array([2, 9, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 8, 6, 8])
```

The actual code you need (TLDR;):

```
counts = pd.DataFrame(pd.value_counts(yourlist))
pd.merge(left=df, left_index=True,
         right=counts, right_index=True,
         how='left').fillna(0)
```

Comment: The OP has an external list they want to use though, the data is not in a df yet